# Files downloaded from my Ubuntu server appear to be treated as text, regardless of their type - How to fix?

Tags: server, apache2, ftp, mime-type

I am running Ubuntu server 10.04.1 on an x86 box, and all seems ok, however, I have also installed apache2 and proftpd, and configured them as per documentation.

I am having problems when I download non-text files (Binaries, images, etc) they appear to be treated as text, resulting in an unusable file received by the client machine. I have tried both vsftpd and currently proftpd on the server with the same result. When downloading files using http (from the Apache server) the same thing occurs. I tried removing ufw (the firewall) and rebooting, but it made no difference. It seems that the problem lies within Ubuntu itself, and it is a serious problem, as it makes this machine useless as a web server.

Is there a fix and what is it please?

Comment: How did you put those files on the server?

Comment: JanC - I tried 2 methods, firstly, a USB drive, and secondly, via Binary FTP. I checked the files while on the server and they are intact, it is not until I download them from the server to the client machine (using binary FTP or HTTP in firefox) that the corruption occurs. It appears that the files'mime-header is being altered, rendering the file unusable.

Comment: Is there any encryption involved?

Comment: No encryption. The files are fine when uploaded, and if I copy them from the server using sneakernet (or any other non-network method) they are fine.

Comment: If you still have the system available ,can you try 'sudo apt-get install libwww-perl' followed by 'HEAD http://path/to/file' and show the full output?

Answer (score 2):

If you leave it be, Apache is configured to do the right thing. It determines a file's content and serves the correct MIME type. Try the following:

- Use an example file of a common file type: JPEG.
- Check whether the server really returns the wrong MIME type. To do this, use curl locally, e.g.:

  `curl -I http://localhost/file.jpg`

  The MIME type should appear in the header.
- Change back to the default configuration (the one from the Ubuntu package). Apache configuration can be somewhat tricky to get right. Put files in the www (probably `/var/www`)
- Make incremental changes from a known-good to a known-bad configuration. This way you can figure out where you misstepped.

Your difficulties with `proftpd` are probably a different problem altogether.

Comment: Thanks guys - I ended up starting again with Ubuntu server 10.10, and voila! No problem now. (Actually, I just elected to install LAMP) - and then VSFTPD too :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. It's usually instructive to fix this type of problem by trying to discover the root cause, however. As you are well aware this is not a 10.10 vs 10.04 problem.

Comment: Note that apache does not actually inspect the file's contents to "determine its content" by default.. it does so by extension only, as inspecting the files' contents would be a drain on performance. If that behavior is desired, 'sudo a2enmod mime_magic' followed by 'sudo service apache2 restart' will enable that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Apache "mime" module is not enabled? Try enabling it:

```
sudo a2enmod mime
```

Then check your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf` for further details. You may need to examine your `/etc/mime.types` file as well which contains the mappings from extensions to MIME types. And for way more details, see the official [Apache mod_mime documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html).

Comment: Thanks - but I am afraid that this is not the issue, as the mime module is already enabled in apache2, and my mime.types file is in existence in the /etc directory and appears to be correct. It does seem like a mime issue, but none of the usual remedies appear to be working here. Thank you for trying anyway :)

Comment: Did I mention, that this phenomenon occurs when GETing files via FTP. Files uploaded to the server are fine, the corruption does not occur until I retrieve files from the server. It makes no difference if I use a windows or linux client, the fault is still present.